# How can I connect S3 protcol via http?

Tags: open-source, qnap, cyberduck

> [Client] Cyberduck ver 5.3.7 on Mac(Serria)
>
> [Host] QNAP TS853A (application) Object Storage Server

I would like to connect Object Storage Server of QNAP by S3(Amazon simple storage service).
I made he "hdd01" of a storage account name and added user to it.

Then I'll try to connect it by Cyberduck application.
But I can't set URL : "http://...".
How can I set up http protcol?

By the way, I have no experience of connecting.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install a [generic S3 HTTP profile](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/s3#GenericS3profiles) from wich is available in two variants

- Authentication with signature version AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
- Authentication with signature version AWS2